# DbfRead: get the record values from one database and use it in another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbf

I have this Python program with a for loop(Not EOF loop). Inside the for loop, I assign record values to strSsn and strStoreid, but I want to use them inside another database loop. When I use them AFTER the loop I set them in, I only find the value for the last record in the loop I set them in.

```
with DBF(r'C:\Sonichr\\empInfo.DBF',lowernames=True,load =True,ignore_missing_memofile=True) as empInfo_table:                    
    for empInfo_rec in empInfo_table:
        #Append the records in a list
        strSsn = empInfo_rec['ssn']
        strStoreid = empInfo_rec['storeid']

s20data_table = DBF('C:\Sonichr\\s20data.DBF',lowernames=True,load =True,ignore_missing_memofile=True)                   
for s20data_rec in s20data_table:
    storeId = s20data_rec['storeid']
    ssn = s20data_rec['ssn']
    positionde = s20data_rec['positionde']
    payrate = s20data_rec['payrate']

    if storeId + ssn == strStoreId + strSsn:
        if  positionde == 'Carhop' :
            abraPayRate1 = payrate
        else:
            abraPayRate0 = payrate
```

Updated!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please explain whats' the required output? perhaps with examples of both input and output? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok so basically if I 'print strSsn' inside my empInfo_table for loop it print muliple records of a social security number. The same for all the other variables but different data. I'm trying to have it where it can loop 'if storeId + ssn == strStoreId + strSsn' here and get all the records for 'strSsn, strStoreid' to see if it's equal for the condition.

Comment: That doesn't look like my `dbf` library -- where does `DBF` come from?

Comment: Your're right I thought I was using yours..this what I'm using https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ if you think yours is better I would like to see examples of your module if you don't mind because I cannot find any updated dbf information everything is outdated

Comment: Is this outdated is there a updated version? https://pythonhosted.org/dbf/ Im using Python 3.7

Comment: No, that's not current -- I need to figure out how to get that taken down.

Comment: As for your question: your indentation is off, please fix that.  Also, update the question itself with a couple example records, and the output you want.

Comment: @Ethan Furman do you have a more updated version I could use?

Comment: It's fixed in my code it was acting funny to fix on here,.

Comment: It needs to be fixed here.  Copy/paste your corrected code inside the triple-tick marks.

Comment: Can you email me @Ethan Furman or can we do a private chat ?

Comment: From looking at your guide that you said isn't current will help me complete this project I'm working on.

Comment: You can email me using ethan at stoneleaf dot us.

Comment: I emailed you before I think from marquis@eighthr.com check your email?

Comment: @user13269772: Hey, I emailed you back, but you don't seem to have gotten it -- maybe check your spam filters?